# Very basic singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

Here is implementation for singly linkedlist. Any suggestions are most welcome

```
package linkedlist;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class linkedlist {
    private int size=0;
    private Node newNode,oldNode,firstNode,displayNode;

    public void createNode(String value) {
        if(size==0) {
            newNode=new Node(value,null);
            firstNode=newNode;
            size++;
        }
        else {
            oldNode=newNode;
            newNode=new Node(value,null);
            oldNode.setNextNode(newNode);
            size++;

        }

    }

    public void DisplayLinklist() {
        displayNode=firstNode;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(displayNode.getItem());
            displayNode=displayNode.next;
            if(displayNode.next==null) {
                System.out.println(displayNode.getItem());
                break;
            }

        }
    }


    private class Node{
        private String item;
        private Node next;

        Node(String item,Node next){
            this.item=item;
            this.next=next;
        }

        public String getItem() {
            return this.item;
        }

        public void setNextNode(Node address) {
            this.next=address;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        linkedlist mylinklist=new linkedlist();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string value you want to save or press 'n'");
        String input=in.next();
        while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            mylinklist.createNode(input);
            System.out.println("Enter the string value you want to save or press 'n'");
            input=in.next();
        }

        mylinklist.DisplayLinklist();

    }

}
```

This is very basic version and first time I  am doing `Linkedlist`. I am not using any iteration, but just wanted to confirm am I on the right path?

Comment: You should have called it _very basic_ instead of .. :p Are you planning a follow-up with full implementation?

Comment: yes @dfhwze.. i am learning datastructures so was trying it

Comment: Here is an interesting link about what Linus Torvalds considers "good taste" code. He uses a linked-list as example to show, how to improve your code, so it is more clean. You may also be interested in the slashdot article/comments linked  in the blog article. https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- `size++` should be extracted from both branches and called only once
- there is no need to cache instance variables where local method variables should be used instead: `newNode,oldNode,displayNode`
- prefer `while(currentNode != null)` over `while(true)` and `currentNode` should start with `firstNode` and be chained inside the while-loop as `currentNode = currentNode.next`
- you should also provide `remove` and iterator functionality
- `DisplayLinklist` should not be inside this class and it should be camel cased
- variable `firstNode` is usually called `head`
- class `linkedlist` should be called `LinkedList`
- get rid of unwanted blank lines

Answer (score 8):

I can add that instead of `DisplayLinklist()` you should override `toString()` that returns a `String` representation of the linked list. then the caller can decide where and how to display this `String`.

Answer (score 7):

You can have following changes:

1. createNode
   size++ done outside of if..else..
2. In Node constructor if param next is always null then no need of this param.
3. class and method name should be in camelcase as per java convention.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't the *really* basic linked list. For the *most* basic way of doing linked lists, you would get rid of `class linkedlist` entirely, and have `class Node` be the entire implementation. You need both getters and setters for both `item` and `next`, and those four plus the constructor are really the only primitive operations there are. Every other list operation is an algorithm built on those 5 primitives.

It sounds like what you're trying to do is an exercise in stripping the idea of linked lists down to its essence. To do that, you need to wrap your head around the fact that there's no difference between having "a list" and having "the node at the head of a list"; each node *is* a list; and a list is nothing but the nodes and items that make it up.